# Assigning number to word in a string in python

Tags: python, string, numbers, compression

hi i have a compression task in python to develop code where if the input is

`'hello its me, hello can you hear me, hello are you listening'`

Then the output should be

`1,2,3,1,4,5,6,3,1,7,5,8`

Basically each word is assigned a numerical value and if the word is repeated so is the word.
This coding is in python, please help me thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything? StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is to use a dict, when you find a new word add a key/value pairing using an incrementing variable, when you have seen the word before just print the value from the dict:

```
s = 'hello its me, hello can you hear me, hello are you listening'


def cyc(s):
    # set i to 1 
    i = 1
    # split into words on whitespace
    it = s.split()
    # create first key/value pair 
    seen = {it[0]: i}
    # yield 1 for first word
    yield i
    # for all var the first word
    for word in it[1:]:
        # if we have seen this word already, use it's value from our dict
        if word in seen:
            yield seen[word]
        # else first time seeing it so increment count
        # and create new k/v pairing
        else:
            i += 1
            yield i
            seen[word] = i


print(list(cyc(s)))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 7, 5, 8]
```

You can also avoid slicing by using `iter` and calling `next` to pop the first word, also if you want to make `foo == foo!` we need to remove any punctuation from the string which cam be done with *str.rstrip*:

```
from string import punctuation
def cyc(s):
    i = 1
    it = iter(s.split())
    seen = {next(it).rstrip(punctuation): i}
    yield i
    for word in it:
        word = word.rstrip(punctuation)
        if word in seen:
            yield seen[word]
        else:
            i += 1
            yield i
            seen[word] = i
```

Answer (score 2):

How about building a `dict` with item:index mapping:

```
>>> s
'hello its me, hello can you hear me, hello are you listening'
>>> 
>>> l = s.split()
>>> d = {}
>>> i = 1
>>> for x in l:
        if x not in d:
            d[x]=i
            i += 1


>>> d
{'its': 2, 'listening': 8, 'hear': 6, 'hello': 1, 'are': 7, 'you': 5, 'me,': 3, 'can': 4}
>>> for x in l:
        print(x, d[x])


hello 1
its 2
me, 3
hello 1
can 4
you 5
hear 6
me, 3
hello 1
are 7
you 5
listening 8
>>>
```

If you don't want any punctuations in your split list, then you can do:

```
>>> import re
>>> l = re.split(r'(?:,|\s)\s*', s)
>>> l
['hello', 'its', 'me', 'hello', 'can', 'you', 'hear', 'me', 'hello', 'are', 'you', 'listening']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict

text = 'hello its me, hello can you hear me, hello are you listening'
words = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  text).split()
uniq_words = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(words))
res = [uniq_words.index(w) + 1 for w in words]

print(res)  # [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 1, 7, 5, 8]
```