# How do I assign numbers to sentences?

Tags: python-3.x, random, numbers, sentence

I am trying to do this

```
proverbs = "a bad excuse is better than none","A bad workman blames his tools," etc.
```

```
number_of_proverb = random.randint (1,38)
```

```
proverb = sentence number number_of_proverb
```

But I have no idea how to assign numbers to sentences. Thank you, beforehand, for all of your help.

PS 38 because there are 38 sentences. Also is this

```
proverbs = "something something","something something","something, something"
```

correct? Sorry for these basic questions but I just started.

Comment: Sorry, could be me being tired, but I actually have no clue what you want to do. Could you clarify?

Comment: Look into python dictionary. And this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36186716/assigning-number-to-word-in-a-string-in-python

Comment: Why do you want to assign numbers to sentences? What kind of numbers? Please include the expected output.

Comment: Do you want to map numbers to sentences? You might want to do some research about arrays.

Comment: @andrbrue Hangman with common proverbs. Random generation of these problems. To do that I want to assign numbers to them and chose numbers instead of full sentences.

Comment: @DYZ look how i responded to andrbrue's comment

Comment: @DYZ The expected output are 38 sentences with assigned numbers.

Comment: I suspect you want to have a list of 38 sentences but access them by a number, e.g. you want to say "give me the 7. sentence" or a random one. If this is the case and only into this direction (meaning you do not have a sentence and then want to get its number) you should use lists. I recommend reading some documentation about lists as they are a central topic of programming python. I am still unsure if this solves your problem as it is very difficult to understand your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do. You are making a list of proverbs and you want to randomly select one from a list. So it would be best to store your proverbs in a list and use `random.choice` to select them from that list.

```py
proverbs = ["this proverb","that proverb","something, something", "another"]

random.choice(proverbs)
```

- [How to randomly select an item from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306400/how-to-randomly-select-an-item-from-a-list)

If you want to have a number associated with the proverbs, you can just use the `index` function to get the position of the proverb in the list. Like this:

```py
proverbs.index("another")
```

Output:

```
3
```

- [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Robert and @andrbrue. I did this.

```
proverbs = ["A bad excuse is better than none.","A bad workman blames his tools."
```

(there are 38 proverbs)

```
rp = (proverbs[random.randint(1,38)])
```

I still have some problems but I'll figure them out. Thx so much